# Getting select, draggable and contenteditable to work together

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm working on an application that relies heavily on drag and drop. while working on it I've run into a few problems with getting select, draggable and contenteditable to work well with each other. What works in chrome wont work on firefox and vice-versa.

In firefox, selecting works fine if you remove draggable from all elements above it. In chrome you've to disable contenteditable for the selection to work.

I've made a minimal representation of the problem on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2nrpa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

When a user clicks to edit a contenteditable piece of text I want to make the text to be auto-selected so they can easily replace it. This text lies somewhere inside a draggable div. 
Achieving this in both Chrome and Firefox has not been very successful so far.

In most cases selection doesn't work at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please put code responsible for dragging into your question. Link to stackblitz is helpful, but it may become dead in future. Also describe what have you tried for chrome and firefox and the issues.

Comment: I added the code for the drag functionality.

Answer (score 0):

for auto select you can use @ViewChild it will be something like this

```
<div #example  draggable="true">
  <p contenteditable="true" class="select">
    Sample paragraph
  </p>
</div>
<button (click)="toggle()">Click to toggle draggable</button>
```

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private selected = false;
  @ViewChild('example', { static: false }) element;
  toggle(){
    this.element.draggable=!this.element.draggable;
    const item = this.element.nativeElement.children[0];
    this.selected = true;
    item.focus();
  }

  pFocus(event: FocusEvent) {
    if(this.selected) {
     document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
     this.selected = false;
    }
  }
}
```